# TreePlot, VertexRenderingFunction and stretched vertices issue

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0.1 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

Recently I found the following `TreePlot` issue. For simplicity, I took an example from [Mathematica Tree Drawing Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TreeDrawing.html#1950334) and set `TreePlot` orientation to `Left`:

```
TreePlot[{1 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 8, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 8, 6 -> 8, 7 -> 8, 7 -> 9}, Left,
    VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], Yellow, Disk[#1, 0.2], 
        Black, Text[#2, #1]} &)]
```

[image: TreePlot with Left orientation]

But when I specified the root node to `5` (which differs from an automatically selected root node `4`), I recieved an image with stretched verticies:

```
TreePlot[{1 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 8, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 8, 6 -> 8, 7 -> 8, 7 -> 9}, Left, 5,
    VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], Yellow, Disk[#1, 0.2], 
        Black, Text[#2, #1]} &)]
```

[image: TreePlot with Left orientation and root node 5]

Is there a generic solution to this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that there is a bug in how `TreePlot` handles its default `AspectRatio -> Automatic` option:

```
tp = TreePlot[{1 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 8, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 8, 6 -> 8, 7 -> 8,
    7 -> 9}, Left, 5, 
  VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], Yellow, Disk[#1, 0.2],
       Black, Text[#2, #1]} &), AspectRatio -> Automatic]
Options[tp, AspectRatio]
```

> [image: plot]
>
> {AspectRatio -> 0.632456}

One workaround is to reset this option to `Automatic` again using `Show`:

```
Show[TreePlot[{1 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 8, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 8, 6 -> 8, 7 -> 8,
    7 -> 9}, Left, 5, 
  VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], Yellow, Disk[#1, 0.2],
       Black, Text[#2, #1]} &)], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

> [image: plot]

The reason why the form of a disk is affected by `AspectRatio` is that you specify the disk radius in the scale of intrinsic coordinate system of the `Graphics` object:

```
Row[Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 150, 
    AspectRatio -> #] & /@ {1, .5}]
```

> [image: plots]

If you specify the disk radii via `Offset` (in printer's points) the form of the disk will never be affected by `AspectRatio`:

```
TreePlot[{1 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 8, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 8, 6 -> 8, 7 -> 8, 
  7 -> 9}, Left, 5, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], Yellow, 
     Disk[#1, Offset[{20, 20}]], Black, Text[#2, #1]} &)]
```

> [image: plot]

As suggested in the comments, it is easier to adjust the disk radius if one specify it in the form `Offset[r {1,1}]` where `r` is the radius in printer's points.

Comment: More accurate to say radius will not be stretched when the argument is a list of the form `{r, r}` and best to specify it with `r {1, 1}`, which makes it easier to adjust.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Good catch. +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
TreePlot[{1 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 8, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 8, 6 -> 8, 7 -> 8, 7 -> 9}, 
     Left, 5, VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], Yellow, Disk[#1, 0.2], 
     Black, Text[#2, #1]} &), AspectRatio -> .5]
```

[image]