# How to use PlotRange -> All with ListLogLinearPlot?

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 8.0 and fixed in 10.0.0**

---

I would like to generate a `ListLogLinearPlot` that automatically shows all the data points. However the option `PlotRange -> All` does not achieve this. Why does `All` not include all of the data in this case?

For Example:

```
x = Range[0.001, 1000];
y = 5 - Log[x];
ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}], PlotRange -> All]
ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{x, y}], PlotRange -> All]
```

In the resulting plots, the `ListPlot` looks as expected:

[image: listplot]

but the `LisLogLinearPlot` cuts off several points on the left:

[image: listloglinearplot]

Comment: `ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{x, y}], PlotRange -> {Full, All}, 
 Frame -> True]` will work too.

Comment: **appears to be fixed in V10 (OS X 10.9.4)**

Comment: Related: [(30001)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30001/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update for version 10.0.0

The bug in how `ListLogLinearPlot` calculates explicit value for `PlotRange -> All` was finally fixed in version 10.0.0 (July 2014). But the underlying principle is still the same: instead of just passing `PlotRange -> All` for the FrontEnd it calculates explicit value of the plot range in the Kernel. The calculated value differs from the one selected by the FrontEnd which can be obtained using the [`plotRange` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18040/280):

```
x = Range[0.001, 1000];
y = 5 - Log[x];
pl = ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{x, y}], PlotRange -> All];
PlotRange /. Options[pl, PlotRange]
plotRange[Show[pl, PlotRange -> All]]
```

> ```
> {{-7.19556, 6.90676}, {-1.90676, 11.9078}}
> {{-7.41591, 6.90676}, {-1.90676, 11.9078}}
> ```

---

### Original answer

There already was a [discussion](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Jan/msg00320.html) of this issue on MathGroups three years ago. Darren Glosemeyer (Wolfram Research) confirmed that this is a bug:

> The fact that `All` does not show all the points is a bug in the
>   log-based  plotting code which I think will be fixed in the next
>   release.
>
> I get confused about the difference between `All` and `Full` as well. I'm 
>   told by the developer of `PlotRange` that `PlotRange->Full` uses the 
>   `PlotRange->All` result and then does some clipping. The clipping is 
>   similar (at least in concept and perhaps even in the internal code) to
>   a  applying a `RegionFunction`. So there is a difference between `All` and
>   `Full`, but it's somewhat subtle (more subtle than I completely
>   understand).
>
> Darren Glosemeyer
>
> Wolfram Research

The bug becomes clear if one checks the value of `PlotRange` of the plot generated:

```
x = Range[0.001, 1000];
y = 5 - Log[x];
pl = ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{x, y}], PlotRange -> All, 
   Frame -> True, Axes -> False];
Options[pl, PlotRange]
```

> {PlotRange -> {{2.8389, 6.90676}, {-1.90676, 11.9078}}}

It is not `All` as it should. To fix this one needs to reset `PlotRange` to `All` again:

```
pl2 = Show[pl, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

Using `plotRange` function from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18040/280) one can determine absolute value for `PlotRange -> All` (without `PlotRangePadding`):

```
plotRange[pl2]
```

> ```
> {{-6.90776, 6.90676}, {-1.90676, 11.9078}}
> ```

One can see that it is substantiantly wider than the value generated by `ListLogLinearPlot`. So it is clearly a bug in how `ListLogLinearPlot` handles `PlotRange -> All`. It basically has the same nature as [the bug in handling `AspectRatio -> Automatic` by `TreePlot`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47095/280): in the both cases the developer tries to calculate in the Kernel absolute value for a `Dynamic` option which *by definition* can be handled only by `FrontEnd` and get predictable failure on this way.

Answer (score 5):

I've plotted quite a lot... and I still don't know what's the difference...

> `All` -> all points are included
>
> `Full` -> include full range of original data

Clearly, `All` behaves here as `Automatic`:

> `Automatic` -> outlying points are dropped

I've thought, maybe "all points" refers to the precalculated list of points, but the outlier **is** there, even if invisible:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{x, y}], PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True
  ] // {#, Cases[#, Point[x_] :> E^x[[1, 1]], ∞]} &
```

[image]

For me it's clearly a bug or problem with docs that should stress:

**if you need `All` the data, use `Full`.** :)

```
 ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{x, y}], PlotRange -> Full, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: So if you need `All` the data you use `Full`. But do you use `All` if you need the `Full` set of data? :D

Comment: @Öskå But are you sure you want full set, not all the data? :p

Comment: I'm not sure anymore :( :D

Answer (score 2):

It's the automatic value of the option `PlotRangePadding`, not the `PlotRange` option, that's causing the problem in the `ListLogPlot`. The default `Automatic` value adds 4% to end-point values of the range. This is nowhere enough for the `ListLogPlot` with its extreme range.

All that is needed are user-specified values for the plot range padding on the right- and left-hand sides of the plot.

```
x = Range[0.001, 1000];
y = 5 - Log[x];
ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{x, y}], 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> {{10., .1}, Automatic}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: But if you have 4% more than `All` range it should still show all the points, shouldn't it?

Comment: @kuba. I think the 4% is based on the scaled dimensions of the viewport and not on the plot metric. I'm guessing, but it's the only thing I can think that explains the observed behavior, including why the fix I propose works.

Comment: @m_goldberg I think it is a bug in handling `PlotRange->All` and not in `PlotRangePadding`. See my answer for details.