# Why PlotRange doesn't work for this set of values?

Tags: logarithmic-scale, plotting

This code, doesn't show me data corresponding to x axis values 1000 and 10000

```
    ListLogLinearPlot[{  
{2.`,0.6566004672633555`},{3.`,1.3583960946639664`},  
{4.`,1.9488104079494668`},{5.`,2.2751624091109224`},  
{6.`,2.0481641523922276`},{7.`,1.8076861039841228`},  
{8.`,1.567222153249036`},{9.`,1.3828655013386686`},  
{10.`,1.333307015795397`},{11.`,1.207450315597537`},  
{12.`,1.1053326628916935`},{13.`,1.0461569618818984`},  
{14.`,0.9827412485818572`},{15.`,0.9148871558873501`},  
{16.`,0.8820097240704773`},{17.`,0.8305457378907795`},  
{18.`,0.7840815651752284`},{19.`,0.7418232652693492`},  
{20.`,0.7037798895571512`},{101.`,0.2777401685500814`},  
{1000.`,0.09241053289867017`},{10000.`,0.029907070416454667`}  
},PlotRange->All]
```

I tried specifying PlotRange->All and PlotRange->{{0.,10001.},All}, but it didn't help. Could anyone please clarify what could be the problem?

Comment: PlotRange->Full seems to do what you want.

Comment: @KAI thanks, it does indeed.

Comment: Duplicate of "[How to use PlotRange -> All with ListLogLinearPlot?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47393/280)"

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov thanks, it's clear now.

Answer (score 5):

```
ListLogLinearPlot[{{2.`, 0.6566004672633555`}, {3.`, 
   1.3583960946639664`}, {4.`, 1.9488104079494668`}, {5.`, 
   2.2751624091109224`}, {6.`, 2.0481641523922276`}, {7.`, 
   1.8076861039841228`}, {8.`, 1.567222153249036`}, {9.`, 
   1.3828655013386686`}, {10.`, 1.333307015795397`}, {11.`, 
   1.207450315597537`}, {12.`, 1.1053326628916935`}, {13.`, 
   1.0461569618818984`}, {14.`, 0.9827412485818572`}, {15.`, 
   0.9148871558873501`}, {16.`, 0.8820097240704773`}, {17.`, 
   0.8305457378907795`}, {18.`, 0.7840815651752284`}, {19.`, 
   0.7418232652693492`}, {20.`, 0.7037798895571512`}, {101.`, 
   0.2777401685500814`}, {1000.`, 0.09241053289867017`}, {10000.`, 
   0.029907070416454667`}}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: Eldo, thanks. However, why doesn't PlotRange->{{0.,10001.},All} work?

Comment: @user1541776 - The documentation of `PlotRange` is a little bit vague here. It defines `All` as "all points are included" and `Full` as "include full range of original data". A potential trap in my eyes. Therefore: Thanks for this very good question :)

Comment: thank you for the comment and welcome for the question :-)