# PlotRange -> All vs Full?

Tags: plotting, graphics, options

What is the difference between `PlotRange -> Full` and `PlotRange -> All` in a `Plot`, `ListPlot`, `ContourPlot`, etc.? Or in `Graphics`? Here is what the Documentation page for [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) says under the **Details** section:

> `PlotRange -> All`    "all points are included"
>
> `PlotRange -> Full`     "include full range of original data"

The difference is not clear to me. In the examples I tried both options have the same effect.

Comment: Example where they have different behaviours: `Show[ListPlot[{1, 3}], ListPlot[{6, 5}], PlotRange -> All]` works, but it no longer if you replace `All` with `Full`.

Comment: From the documentation:
Use PlotRange->All to include all points.
Use PlotRange->Full to include all the points and the original domain.
[Mathematica Documentation - PlotRange](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html)

Comment: Check this post [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47406/42848), especially this part _"I get confused about the difference between All and Full as well. I'm told by the developer of PlotRange that PlotRange->Full uses the PlotRange->All result and then does some clipping."_ Note, however, that this is for ListLogLinearPlot, not sure if the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 25):

[Straight from the Docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Full.html):

> Normally, `PlotRange -> All` shows only the existing points:

```
Plot3D[Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

> `PlotRange -> Full` specifies that a plot should include the full range of values of input variables:

```
Plot3D[Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: I have taken the liberty to improve wording of your answer. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, thank you very much!